# color values different per monitor with getpixel/lockbits

Tags: c#, pixel, getpixel, lockbits

Im trying to make a method that returns the color value of a specific pixel. The problem i am having it that the same piece of code returns a different ARGB on different monitors.

Currently im using this method:

```
    public static Color GetColorFromPosition(string process, int x, int y)
    {
        //using bitmap object to do actions
        using (Bitmap Capture = CaptureApplication(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process)))
        {
            //copy specific part of screen and push it into bmp
            Color result = Capture.Clone(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1), Capture.PixelFormat).GetPixel(0,0);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

The captureapplication method looks like this (method takes a snapshot of an open application):

```
    public static Bitmap CaptureApplication(string procName)
    {
        Rectangle clientArea = GetProcessWindowRect(procName);

        Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(clientArea.Width, clientArea.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(clientArea.Left, clientArea.Top, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        return bp;
    }
```

This captures an application window thats open and then gets the ARGB value of the given pixel using getpixel. So to give an example i want the color at x=100 and y=100. On computer one it would return [A=255, R=6, G=158, B=12] and on the other computer i get [A=255, R=6, G=157, B=13]. The results are slightly different.

My question is why does this happen and it there a solution? I've also tried using lockbits instead of getpixel but the same problem persists.

Comment: Are both computers set to 32 bit color quality?

Comment: The drivers of the monitors are different.  The bit map has a width and height which will vary with the size of the monitor.  You can have a bitmap that is a pictur 5"" x 7"" and a monitor the is 24" x 36" inches.  So the driver is scaling the bitmap to the screen and also averaging the colors.

Comment: @JaydeepJadav they are both at "1920 by 1080, True Color (32bit), 60 hertz"

Comment: What are thoe pixels? Images? Zoomed? Compressed? Text? Cleartype? - There are various renderers that will use random dithering..